# Adding in Non-Listed Fields into Saved Searches/Reports

Tags: field, netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to create a saved search of Work Order Completion transaction records, with two of the criteria being the Starting and Ending Operations.  In the default transaction search field dropdowns, I am unable to find the Starting Operation, or Ending Operation fields.

I tried creating a Formula (Text) line in the criteria to get around this.  For the Starting Operation, the field ID is "startoperation", so in my Formula field, I typed in {startoperation}.  I was expecing to see the values populated once I ran the search, but instead, that particular columns is showing "ERROR: Field Not Found".  I am guessing that I am missing something quite simple.  Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Some fields are not available on Saved Searches and even if you use their IDs they won't be accepted. Besides, for some fields, the field ID that you can see on the form or use in script is not the same as the one to be used on Searches and based on the Schema Browser page https://2545798.app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2023_1/script/record/transaction.html the field you mentioned is not listed as a Transaction search filter or result.

So, what you can try to do is create a Custom field to copy the value in the standard field in it, and this can be done in two ways:

1. Set your custom field to be a Non-Stored field and set its value to be copied from the standard field using the config under the Default value or the Sourcing subtabs (I tested it and you can add a Non-Stored value as a saved search result column)
2. If option 1 doesn't work, then you will have to copy the value yourself using Scripts or Workflows (you can use User Event script or workflow for realtime update of the custom field when the record is edited, or you can use Map/Reduce or scheduled script if you can't track realtime changes). You can also use Mass Update or Map/Reduce script to update the custom field value on existing records.

Once you were able to get the value of the original field into the new custom field, you can use the new field in your search.